# Positive vs. negative in options/settings?

Tags: settings

What is better phrasing for settings pages when dealing with true/false/checkbox values? For example the setting that hides something. How would you name it:

`– Hide x (disabled by default) -> user must select to hide
- Show x (enabled by default) -> user must deselect to hide`

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one thing, then I would choose the opposite of the default. So if something is shown by default, then use Hide checkbox.

But if there are many checkboxes in one pane, each to show/hide something, then it definitely must be the same for all, and I would go for Show.